# Jboss EAP 5 and Tomcat 6 on the same Win env. (Jboss gets Toncat`s home page when`s up)

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I`m newbie to Java technologies, just trying to catch up some idea of it. 
I was trying to build a java environment to play with Eclipse, Mysql, Tomcat and Jboss and integrate these together.
I did:
1. Installed jdk1.6.0_20 (including JAVA_HOME and path variables; I work on Win Vista), mysql 5 and eclipse-jee-galileo (the latest one, 3.6 I believe) and all went good - java programs are compiled and run getting a DB connection.
2. Installed Jboss enterprise-installer-5.0.1.jar with localhost:8080 and this also went good - run.bat started it and I could log in as admin thru its home page. I integrated it with eclipse and could start and stop it from there too.
3. I got apache-tomcat-6.0.26-windows-x86 and this also runs and stops from command line and from eclipse. But this one uses localhost:8080 without asking.

Now the problem is when I start jboss I get Tomcat home page and I can`t fix it. Is it probably because both now use localhost:8080? BTW, does Jboss EAP 5 contain Tomcat inside and I shouldn't add that Tomcat separately?

Thanks for you help in advance,
Eddie

Answer (score 1):

port 8080 is the default port used by tomcat and other servlet containers and yes, JBoss is using tomcat under the hood.

You need to move the port(s) of JBoss or Tomcat.

For tomcat you need to open /conf/server.xml with a text editor and search for 'port='.

You'll find the http connector, https connector, mod_jk, etc. I think only port 8080 and 8009 are enabled by default

move all these to for example 18080 and 18009 etc...

Then you can run them both side-by-side.

You do not really need to as JBoss can also deploy your war files.

If you want a fast container for testing consider Jetty as it starts very fast compared to the 2 above.

Comment: Hi Peter,

Thanks for your quick response. 
Just moved ports 8080 and 8009 of Tomcat to 18080 and 18009 as you advised and this works for Tomcat but still when Jboss is up (even with no Tomcat by its side) by going to http://localhost:8080/ I get Tomcat home page. 

Any idea?

Thanks again,
Eddie

Comment: By changing the ports the tomcat stop command cannot stop the running instance anymore. To verify : Turn them both off, verify nothing is listening anymore on port 8080. If so, kill it using the Process Manager. If you are sure 8080 is free, start up the JBoss server, preferably from the commandline : then you can see what is happening. You should now see the Tomcat page with Jboss decorations. Start the tomcat, again preferably from the command line, and verify 18080 is working fine.

Comment: thanks! I got Jboss home page only by going http://localhost:8080/index.html
So I believe it was Firefox who always redirected me to a stored tomcat home page. Thanks again for your assistance. I will definitely check Jetty too. We'll be in touch when I will add it to my java env. :)) 
Have a good one!
me